# Gram-Schmidt procedure on functions

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

I have been applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure with great success however i am having difficulty in the next step, applying it to polynomials.

Here i what i understand
If i have 2 functions, say $x^2$ and $x^3$, and want this to work over -1 to 1, then

$$ V_1=U_1 = x^2$$
great, now for $V_2$

$$ V_2 = U_2 - \dfrac{<U_2,V_1>}{||V_1||^2}V_1 $$

This is where i dont understand
$$ V_2 = x^3 -\dfrac{\int_{-1}^1 B}{\int_{-1}^1x^4}x^2 $$
If i have done everything correctly, then how do i proceed, how do i get B and get $V_2$?

Comment: Keep in mind that functions and polynomials are not the same thing. Also, you need to state which inner product you're working with. And finally, what do you mean by $B$ in your last equation?

Comment: By $B$ i mean i know a function should go here, but what is B? I am not sure what you mean by which inner product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just using the integral to define your inner product:$$\langle f,g\rangle := \int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)dt.$$

In your case you have $U_1 = V_1 = x^2$, $U_2 = x^3$, hence, as you correctly wrote, the formula for $V_2$ is:

$$ V_2 = U_2 - \frac{\langle U_2,V_1\rangle}{||V_1||^2}V_1 = U_2 - \frac{\langle U_2,V_1\rangle}{\langle V_1 ,V_1\rangle}V_1 =x^3 - \frac{\int_{-1}^1t^3 \cdot t^2\,dt}{\int_{-1}^1t^2\cdot t^2\,dt}x^2 = x^3$$
since the integral in the numerator equals $0$.

Comment: Thank you, so in general i just multiple the 2 functions and integrate. Only concern is in this example are we not dividing by 0? Also do we multiply x^2 after the integration? we cannot bring it in the integral i assume?

Comment: We are not dividing by $0$ since the integral in the denominator is 2/5. maybe the notation is confusing: the "x" in the integral is not the same "x" outside the integral, let me edit replacing the former with "t" and then it will be clear that moving the x^2 inside the integral has no effect (it is a constant with respect to the variable of integration)

Comment: Sure, but why isnt the integral of $t^3 \times t$ the same as the integral as $t^2 \times t^2$